# Issue with string manipulation

Tags: powerbi, dax

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong. I'm appling this code to a new column called TW

```
TW = 
IF(ISBLANK('Tickets'[TimeWorked]), BLANK(),
    IF (SEARCH("(", 'Tickets'[TimeWorked],1,BLANK()), 
        MID('Tickets'[TimeWorked], 
            SEARCH("(", 'Tickets'[TimeWorked], 1, BLANK()) + 1, SEARCH("min", 
            'Tickets'[TimeWorked], 1, BLANK()) - SEARCH("(", 'Tickets'[TimeWorked], 1, BLANK()) - 2),
        LEFT('Tickets'[TimeWorked], SEARCH("min",'Tickets'[TimeWorked],1,BLANK()) **- 2**)
    )
)
```

in the field 'Tickets'[TimeWorked] have 2 value format "15 minutes" or "2.08 hours (125 minutes)"

The error message is "LEFT has the wrong data type or has invalid value" regardless what I tryed, changing with static value in the LEFT statement, nothing works. I know it is related to the "-2" If I remove it, the error message is removed. Same if I put a "+2. Only the "-" is causing the issue and only on the LEFT statement in the flase section of my second IF.

I'm trying to get the minutes value of each field. Would it be possible to get some help with this. Thanks,